# Is mutex locks note working properly? Can't Deadlock

Tags: c++, multithreading, mutex, deadlock

So I'm trying to make a C++ program that should deadlock. With my following code I believe it should work but doesn't deadlock. Either my mutex.lock()'s are not working properly? I mean if mut2.lock() locks the critical section it should unlock until it's done right meaning funcA shouldn't run or at least wait till mut2.unlock()'s since they both use a resources rs2? Why can't I deadlock the program?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <cstdio>   // getchar
#include <thread>   // this_thread, yield
#include <future>   // async
#include <chrono>   // seconds
#include <unistd.h>
using namespace std;
mutex mut1, mut2, mut3;
int rs1=1; int rs2 = 2; int rs3=3;
int MAX = 20;

void funcA(){

    mut1.lock();
    cout<<"mut1 lock for thread A\n";
    for(int i=0; i<MAX; i++){
        rs2 = i;
    cout<<"[Aloop]rs1: "<<rs1<<" rs2: "<<rs2<<" rs3: "<<rs3<<" i:"<<i << endl;
    }
    rs1 = rs2;
    cout<<"[A]rs1: "<<rs1<<" rs2: "<<rs2<<" rs3: "<<rs3 << endl;
    mut1.unlock();
    cout<<"mut1 unlock for thread A\n";
}
void funcB(){

    mut2.lock();
    cout<<"mut2 lock for thread B\n";
    rs3 = rs1 + rs2;
    cout<<"[B]rs3: "<<rs3 << " rs1: "<<rs1 << " rs2: "<<rs2 <<endl;
    sleep(50);
    mut2.unlock();  
    cout<<"mut2 unlock for thread B\n";
}


int main(){
    thread tA(funcA);
    thread tB(funcB);

    tA.join();
    tB.join();

return 0;
}

//Here is my makefile
#Makefile project 2

project2: project2.o
    g++ -std=c++11 -pthread -o project2 project2.o
project2.o: project2.cpp project2.h
    g++ -std=c++11 -Wall -pthread -c project2.cpp
    //Below is my output
```

> mut2 lock for thread B
>
> [B]rs3: 3 rs1: 1 rs2: 99
>
> mut1 lock for thread A
>
> [Aloop]rs1: 1 rs2: 0 rs3: 3 i:0
>
> [Aloop]rs1: 1 rs2: 1 rs3: 3 i:1
>
> [Aloop]rs1: 1 rs2: 2 rs3: 3 i:2
>
> [Aloop]rs1: 1 rs2: 3 rs3: 3 i:3
>
> [Aloop]rs1: 1 rs2: 5 rs3: 3 i:5
>
> [Aloop]rs1: 1 rs2: 6 rs3: 3 i:6
>
> [Aloop]rs1: 1 rs2: 7 rs3: 3 i:7
>
> [Aloop]rs1: 1 rs2: 8 rs3: 3 i:8
>
> [Aloop]rs1: 1 rs2: 9 rs3: 3 i:9
>
> [Aloop]rs1: 1 rs2: 10 rs3: 3 i:10
>
> [Aloop]rs1: 1 rs2: 11 rs3: 3 i:11
>
> [Aloop]rs1: 1 rs2: 12 rs3: 3 i:12
>
> [Aloop]rs1: 1 rs2: 13 rs3: 3 i:13
>
> [Aloop]rs1: 1 rs2: 14 rs3: 3 i:14
>
> [Aloop]rs1: 1 rs2: 15 rs3: 3 i:15
>
> [Aloop]rs1: 1 rs2: 16 rs3: 3 i:16
>
> [Aloop]rs1: 1 rs2: 17 rs3: 3 i:17
>
> [Aloop]rs1: 1 rs2: 18 rs3: 3 i:18
>
> [Aloop]rs1: 1 rs2: 19 rs3: 3 i:19
>
> [A]rs1: 19 rs2: 19 rs3: 3
>
> mut1 unlock for thread A
>
> mut2 unlock for thread B

Comment: It seem as if each of your functions uses a different mutex. So they operate independently.

Comment: Fix the bug in the code and the mystery will go away. Hint: If rs2 is shared, it needs to be protected by **a** mutex. What mutex protects rs2?

Comment: You are misusing the term "deadlock".   A deadlock is a situation where, for example, two threads are each trying to grab a mutex that is already held by the other.   The result is two threads hung, because both are simultaneously waiting on the other to release a mutex, which neither will ever do.     A deadlock is something to avoid .... and your code doesn't deadlock anyway, which is a good thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two threads attempt to lock different mutexes, so there's no way they can deadlock.

While there are many different ways one can imagine threads deadlocking, a deadlock with mutexes cannot occur unless one thread tries to acquire a mutex the other thread holds. (Of course, other things need to happen too. If just that happens, it will simply wait for the other thread to release the mutex rather than deadlocking.)

Comment: So does that mean every resource should have it's own lock, meaning any thread that tries to use for example rs1 would have to lock mut1? Last question is there a reason why funcB is called first compared to funcA since thread A is instantiated first?

Comment: @larus: 1) yes, otherwise different thread can modify shared resource simultaneously = race condition 2) you don't know when `funcB` is called, you just see that its output is printed first. it can be called before or after `funcA`, or at the same time

Comment: @larug That's one approach. Whether that's a sensible approach depends on many factors. As for which function is called first, it's arbitrary. The scheduler is free to run threads in whatever order it finds most efficient.

Comment: @larug, classic deadlock is when thread A is stuck waiting for thread B to do something (like release a mutex), while at the same time, thread B is stuck waiting for thread A to do something (like release a _different_ mutex.)  To force a deadlock using mutexes, you'll need two threads (which you've already got), and two mutexes (ditto), and both threads must try to lock _both_ mutexes.  Also, they have to do it in _opposing order:_  Thread A locks mutex 1, then tries to lock mutex 2 while thread B locks mutex 2, then tries to lock mutex 1.  If the timing is right, you'll get a deadlock.

Answer (score -1):

Your problem is that the resource `rs2` is not "protected" because it is not being protected by a single mutex.  A variable can be accessed by anybody at any time so long as it is within scope.  This is why you use a mutex to avoid two threads from stepping on each others toes.

Try this; use a single mutex and name it something like `rs2Mutex`.  Any time a thread wants to use `rs2` it must lock `rs2Mutex` and only `rs2Mutex`.  This will give you the results you desire.

As a general rule of thumb I always name my mutexes for exactly what they are going to protect.  This helps to avoid confusion and makes troubleshooting easier on both you and the person that follows you later.  It is very heartening to see you experimenting and trying to figure out where things are going wrong.  Keep working at it, and make sure you understand the basic principles, and threads will be much simpler for you down the road.

Comment: Ok it makes sense. Last question is there a reason why funcB is called first compared to funcA since thread A is instantiated first?

Comment: @larug It is up to the OS as to when each thread runs.  You can never, EVER assume that thread A will run before thread B, that they'll get equal time slices, or that they'll get an equal number of "turns" being run.

Comment: I gave different mutex locks for different resources however how am I supposed to deadlock? Even though the threads share resources it doesn't deadlock. Would I have to add like sleep(50) to one of the threads?

Comment: @larug you have to try to lock an already locked mutex.  So, if `rs2` is protected by `rs2Mutex` then when both threads try to lock `rs2Mutex` only the first thread will succeed.  Be sure to make the work you are doing between the lock and unlock long enough to span the possible thread switching done by the OS.  Remember, BOTH threads should try to lock the same mutex.